# CloudTableClient client side timeout

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When using a CloudTableClient, is there a way to specify a *client* side timeout?

The TableRequestOptions RetryPolicy and ServerTimeout control the number of retry attempts, the delay between attempts, and the storage service side timeout, but don't seem to cover a client side per-attempt timeout (like the HttpClient.Timeout property).

My concern with relying on the ServerSideTimeout is with delays connecting to the actual server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When using a CloudTableClient, is there a way to specify a client side timeout?

The MaximumExecutionTime property of TableRequestOptions could help us specific the maximum execution time for all potential retries for the request include the time used by client side and server side.

```
tableClient.DefaultRequestOptions.MaximumExecutionTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
```

A exception will throw if the request can't be handled in the specific time.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.'
```

> like the HttpClient.Timeout property

The Timeout property of HttpClient also specific all the execution time before the response came back.

> I'm hoping to find a per-retry timeout.

I suggest you use the MaximumExecutionTime. If you need a client side DNS resolve timeout, you could get or set the [DnsRefreshTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.dnsrefreshtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property of ServicePointManager.

```
ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 4*60*1000; // 4 minutes
```

Comment: I'm hoping to find a per-retry timeout. As far as I've been able to tell, there isn't one.